# Dynamic data binding with dialog

Tags: sapui5

I have a list with items. After a click I want to open a new dialog and bind it to some detail information about the clicked item.

My data source is a SAP HANA database with an OData interface. The interface looks like:

```
Table/Path: Items
|ID|NAME|PRICE|ITEM_DETAILS (Navigation Property)|

Table/Path: ItemsDetails
|ID|ITEM_ID|...|
```

The list has a binding to `Items`which works fine. On a click, I want to bind my dialog to the navigation property `ITEM_DETAILS` but the new binding does not works. The dialog is still binding/showing to the "old" path `Items` instead of `ItemsDetails`.

The dialog fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <SelectDialog
        id="detailInformation"
        noDataText="No data..."
        title="{item}">
        <StandardListItem
            title="{ID}"
            description="{FREQUENCY}"
            type="Active" />
    </SelectDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

The event handler:

```
if (!this.selectLoadProfile) {
    this.selectLoadProfile = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "de.xxx.view.fragment.Dialog", this);
    this.getView().addDependent(this.selectLoadProfile);
    this.selectLoadProfile.bindElement("ITEM_DETAILS");
}
this.selectLoadProfile.open();
```

Can someone tell me how I can dynamically load the data?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit confusing me, What i understood from that is You have a List in your view on click of list item a dialog is open that contains the item detail which is a navigation property of the item. Below is the code what you are trying.

```
this.selectLoadProfile.bindElement("ITEM_DETAILS");
```

This statement is not specific to which item details you want to bind.so try with below binding path.

```
this.selectLoadProfile.bindElement("ITEM(id)/ITEM_DETAILS");
```

As the above statement is in the condition `(!this.selectLoadProfile)` make sure that execute every time so that binding of Element should update.

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get the Item path in the Click event handler, and bind ItemDetail path to Dialog.

```
onClick:function(oEvent) {
    var oControl = oEvent.getSource();
    var oItemPath = oControl.getBindingContext().getPath();
    var oItemDetailPath = oItemPath + "/ITEM_DETAILS";

    if (!this.selectLoadProfile) {
          this.selectLoadProfile = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), 
                  "de.xxx.view.fragment.Dialog", this);
          this.getView().addDependent(this.selectLoadProfile);

    }
    this.selectLoadProfile.bindElement(oItemDetailPath);
    this.selectLoadProfile.open();
}
```

Comment: Okay now I'm getting the right path. But the details are still wrong. The binding does not want to update. If I use  the `..getModel().refresh()` only the "parent" view is refreshing. It looks as if the fragment is completely outside of the control..

Comment: Did you set your ODataModel bindingMode to ToWay by setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay)?

Comment: Yes, now I have... ;) But the problem still exists. I found the UI5 Inspector for Chrome and found out that the bindingContext is null while my working lists have a bindingContext.. could that be the problem?

Comment: Nope. I can't set the right path. It will not update :/